# Capybara Content not found but actually the content exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

Im facing some strange issue. I wrote a test case for my rails app using capybara, cucumber and poltergeist. See below for code..

```
@javascript
Scenario: admin can search multiple users when different oinkcodes exist
Given a "admin" user exists and is signed in
And the following users with an oinkcode exist:
  | email           | oinkcode                                 |
  | berf@berf.com   | 5f9614e97a5610f99c7d0975a73de43f2414fc96 |
  | sample@berf.com | asd2455a5610f99c7d0975a73de43f2414fc9812 |
When I goto "/oinkcodes/search"
And I fill in "query" with the following lines of text:
  |                    text                |
  |5f9614e97a5610f99c7d0975a73de43f2414fc96|
  |asd2455a5610f99c7d0975a73de43f2414fc9812|
And I click "Go"
And I wait for index   # sleep for 10 sec
#And I do some debugging
Then I should see "berf@berf.com"
And I should see "sample@berf.com"
```

In the above example, when i click on 'Go', through javascript i get the user email addresses. When i run this test, its failing as "content not found (RuntimeError)"........  When i try to debug through pry.

```
pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> page.body
Result: <h3>Users</h3>\n      <textarea class=\"text_area\" id=\"users\" rows=\"15\" cols=\"60\" readonly=\"\">    berf@berf.com\n    sample@berf.com\n</textarea>\n 

pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> find_field('users').value
=> "    berf@berf.com\n    sample@berf.com\n"
[4] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> page.has_content?('berf@berf.com')
=> false
```

I don't understand, why page.has_content? is returning false, when i can see that content in page.body or find_field('users').value...... Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone here, who can help me out.... Or my questions is not good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After google for 1-2 days i got the answer. There is a bug in Capybara that when a text area is filled with javascript, the capybara returns false when we try:

```
page.has_content?
```

even when we can see the result in the UI.
See the link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/4K_EuQO71Ig

Comment: That issue was marked fixed in 2011.  Are you on a VERY old version of capybara?